# How can I get PID to kill a process using PowerShell

Tags: powershell

I'd like to kill all process that are not in a text file `$fileServices`,
I use a loop to got PID to send it to `Stop-Process`.
Runs without error. But the process isn't killed and my loop is not good.

How can I got PID to kill this process using PowerShell please?

```
$ServiceName = Get-WmiObject Win32_Process -Filter "name = 'service.exe'" |
               Select-Object CommandLine
$procId = Get-WmiObject Win32_Process -Filter "name = 'service.exe'" |
          Select-Object ProcessId
$fileServices = Get-Content C:\serviceNotStop.txt

$totalcount = Get-Content C:\serviceNotStop.txt | Measure-Object -Line
$number = $totalcount.Lines

$get_path = $ServiceRunName.CommandLine
$output_file = 'C:\service_name.txt'
$get_path | Out-File -FilePath $output_file

if ($fileServices -ne $null) {
    foreach ($process in $get_path ) {
        foreach ($id in $procId ) {
            $nameExtracted = ($process -split '//')[2]
            $counter = 1
            foreach ($line in $fileServices) {
                if ($line -ne $nameExtracted) {
                    $counter++
                    "continue search file, $counter"
                    if ($counter -gt $number) {
                        " kill process after all search"
                    } else {
                        continue
                    }
                } elseif ($line -eq $nameExtracted) {
                    "keep process $line "
                    break
                }
            }
        }
    }
} else {
    "the file is empty"
}
```

Comment: Do you run the script with admin rights?

Comment: yes, with admin

Comment: At the top of the script you retrieve the service names and assign them to `$ServiceName`, but later in the script you iterate over `$get_path` with gets its value from `$ServiceRunName.CommandLine` - that might have something to do with it

Comment: with $get_path i retrieve the  CommandeLines to write its in file , and i use -split  to extract just the end of commandLine, because with this part, I can compare whether my process is in the file $fileServices  content or not. 

for exemple: 
$get_path content : 
   "C:\Program Files\services\service.exe" //RS//service1
$nameExtarcted : 
    service1 
$fileServices content: 
   service1

Comment: If you're trying to kill services then it could be possible that they're configured to restart in case of a failure.

Answer (score 0):

List.txt contents
    notepad
    chrome
    calculator

```bsh
$list = Get-Content -Path C:\Users\username\Desktop\TEMP\list.txt -Raw


Get-Process | Where-Object ProcessName -Like $list | kill -Force
```

---

I almost have this working, just have to figure out how to get multiple lines in the txt file to be iterated through like an array

Comment: It's so close to being an answer maybe someone can edit in the missing piece to make this iteratively run through the list contents in the text file.  I know it's something very small missing and still trying to pinpoint it to work as a complete answer.

Comment: How about `$list = get-content list.txt; Get-Process $list | kill -force`

Comment: Or have a csv with the header "name", then `import-csv ps.csv | kill`.